# switch/case and if else behaves differently

Tags: php

I have following code

```
<?php

declare (strict_types = 1); // strict requirement

function fun1(int $interval)
{
    $retVal = -10;
    switch ($interval) {
        case ($interval <= 45):
            $retVal = 5;
            break;
        case ((90 <= $interval) && ($interval <= 100)):
            $retVal = 1;
            break;
    }
    return $retVal;
}

function fun2(int $interval)
{
    $retVal = -10;
    if ($interval <= 45){
        $retVal = 5;
    }
    elseif((90 <= $interval) && ($interval <= 100)){
        $retVal = 1;
    }
    return $retVal;
}

echo "FUN1";
echo "<br>";
echo fun1(0); // expected: 5 returned: 1 - ???
echo "<br>";
echo fun1(20); // expected: 5 returned: 5
echo "<br>";
echo fun1(95); // expected: 1 returned: 1
echo "<br>";

echo "FUN2";
echo "<br>";
echo fun2(0); // expected: 5 returned: 5
echo "<br>";
echo fun2(20); // expected: 5 returned: 5
echo "<br>";
echo fun2(95); // expected: 1 returned: 1
echo "<br>";

?>
```

Which returns:

```
FUN1
1
5
1
FUN2
5
5
1
```

For got sake I cannot figure out why `fun1(0)` returns 1 instead of 5

Comment: change `switch ($interval)` to `switch (true)` and it will give you required result. Just in case 0 = false ;) But in case if you don't understand why this happen i suggest to read [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) and look how switch statement compares values in it.

Comment: `switch (0) case 0 <= 45:` translates  to  `if (0 === 0 <= 45)` which is `if (0 === true)`…

Comment: @SergeyLigus @deceze so in other words if I want to use `switch/case` I should stick with exactly one value in `case` statement?

Comment: You can do as you did before, but with what **deceze** explained to you. Switch is trying to compare entire expression in `case` to a variable which you are passing to the switch and in final result interpreter gives you gibberish, cause general condition formed incorrectly. And btw move `$retval = -10;` to a `default` section in order to always get some readable final result. Its the same as final `else` in `if\else` chain. @WakanTanka

Comment: switch(false) { case true : //code ; case false : //code} . is false equal to false or it is equal to true ? having : switch(0) is equal to switch(false).

Comment: @behzadmsalehi **switch/case**  from docs **does loose comparison** which from your example means next if you are passing 0  to switch and you have `case false:` then expression will be next `0 == false` which is **true** and it will execute false case block. Same goes for false... In case if it doesn't find case block with meeting condition result then fallback to **default** so its also important to specify **default** block.